# why the sample and subtract method in spark give results like this

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

```
df=sqlContext.read.parquet("/user/data.parquet")
```

read parquet file

```
df.count()<br/>
```

count

```
8246174
train=df.sample(False,0.8)
test=df.subtract(train)<br/>

train.count()
```

count trainset

```
6594476
test.count()
```

count testset

```
117790
```

apparently, 659w+11w do not equal 824w, javaRDD also has this problem.

Comment: Btw, you probably want to use `randomSplit` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my 800w has duplicate values... it needs to "distinct" before sample